# why the javascript did not get the right day

Tags: javascript

I am a newbie of javascript,today I am facing a strange problem, I am using this code to get the current day:

```
const currentDate = new Date();
console.log(currentDate);
const day = currentDate.getDay();
console.log(day);
```

but the console output look like this:

```
> "2021-11-18T07:29:05.205Z"
> 4
```

why the day is 4 not 18?

Comment: The getDay() method returns the day of the week (0 to 6) of a date.

Comment: I know it , thank you for your patient. @AbuSufian

Comment: You need `getDate`. (Oh and before you ask, with `getMonth` you need `+ 1`. Historical reasons...)